# Android Kotlin: Periodic work manager is not running the function periodically in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, background-task

I am building an Android app using Kotlin and Android Studio. I am trying to run a background task even when the app is dead or completely closed. I am using WorkManager. But it seems to be running just once.

This is my worker class.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters

class RegisterReceiversWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): Worker(context, workerParams) {
    companion object {
        const val WORK_NAME: String = "REGISTER_RECEIVERS_WORKER"
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        registerReceivers()
        return Result.success();
    }

    private fun registerReceivers() {
        Log.i("REGISTER_RECEIVER", "Greeting from the background")
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I am printing out a message in the logcat.

Then I start the worker as follow in the MainActivity when the  app is first opened.

```
 val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<RegisterReceiversWorker>(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(RegisterReceiversWorker.WORK_NAME, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
```

As you can see, it should print out the message every ten seconds. But when I run the app, it is printing out the message in the logcat, just once. What is wrong with my code? How can I make sure that it is running every 10 seconds in the background even when the app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Periodic work needs to be scheduled in an interval longer than [`MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS).